# How to bundle a node module, which has got its own chunks with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, npm-package

I have a node module which has got its own chunks. For example the `dist` folder of the node module looks somewhat like this:

- main.js
- chunk1.js
- chunk2.js
- chunk3.js

The `main.js` dynamically imports other chunks.

I am bundling this with webpack, webpack only including the `main.js`. As a result when the app runs its fails with 404 for rest of the chunks.

If i manually copy paste those chunks inside my app's `build` folder it works fine.

Is there any clean way of acheiving this ? Not want manually copy paste the chunks in the first place.